# How to install geckodriver in Mac terminal? Permission, operation not permitted and no such file directory errors

Tags: python, macos, selenium, terminal, geckodriver

Trying to install geckodriver on mac for Mozilla firefox. 
I think I have installed selenium correctly after reinstalling a million ways with pip and sudo pip but when I trying to install geckodriver using "mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin" or "mv geckodriver /usr/bin" I get an error. The error used to say either "operation not permitted" or give a permissions error but now it says "No such file or directory". Old forms answers to this seem to be outdated or an old attempt may be causing a problem for these other ones.

I tried copying the file using `sudo cp /path/to/geckodriver /usr/local/bin` but after I enter my password I get a "no such file or directory" message again.

Is there a new way to do this? I tried following many forms but they only lead to new problems with outdated solutions.

Side notes: when installing geckodriver I placed in onto my desktop.  I'm trying to mimic this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGU2X5lrz9M  (4:44 in video) which makes it seems as easy as downloading to desktop, typing in `cd Desktop/`  then `mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin` but that obviously isn't working.

Latest attempt:

```
Brandons-MacBook-Pro-3:~ Brandon$ sudo pip install -U selenium 
Password: 
WARNING: The directory '/Users/Brandon/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag. 
WARNING: The directory '/Users/Brandon/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag. 
Requirement already up-to-date: selenium in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (3.141.0) 
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: urllib3 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from selenium) (1.22) 
Brandons-MacBook-Pro-3:~ Brandon$ sudo -H pip intall -U selenium 
ERROR: unknown command "intall" - maybe you meant "install"
Brandons-MacBook-Pro-3:~ Brandon$ sudo -H pip install -U selenium
Requirement already up-to-date: selenium in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (3.141.0) 
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: urllib3 in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from selenium) (1.22) 
Brandons-MacBook-Pro-3:~ Brandon$ /usr/bin
-bash: /usr/bin: is a directory
Brandons-MacBook-Pro-3:~ Brandon$ mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin 
mv: rename geckodriver to /usr/local/bin/geckodriver: No such file or directory 
Brandons-MacBook-Pro-3:~ Brandon$ mv geckodriver /usr/bin
mv: rename geckodriver to /usr/bin/geckodriver: No such file or directory
Brandons-MacBook-Pro-3:~ Brandon$ export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/geckodriver
Brandons-MacBook-Pro-3:~ Brandon$ mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin
mv: rename geckodriver to /usr/local/bin/geckodriver: No such file or directory 
Brandons-MacBook-Pro-3:~ Brandon$ sudo nano /etc/paths
Password: 
Sorry, try again. 
Password:
Brandons-MacBook-Pro-3:~ Brandon$ export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/geckodriver
Brandons-MacBook-Pro-3:~ Brandon$ export $PATH
-bash: export: `/Users/Brandon/anaconda3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/path/to/geckodriver:/path/to/geckodriver': not a valid identifier 
Brandons-MacBook-Pro-3:~ Brandon$ mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin 
mv: rename geckodriver to /usr/local/bin/geckodriver: No such file or directory
Brandons-MacBook-Pro-3:~ Brandon$ sudo cp /path/to/geckodriver /usr/local/bin Password: 
cp: /path/to/geckodriver: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You have to extract the tar file and open terminal where your file is present and then try using "mv geckodriver /usr/bin"

Comment: Or open the terminal and cd into desktop. Check this https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34323/mac-terminal-cd-to-folder-in-current-directory/34325

Comment: @stack how do I extract the tar file? When you say "open up the terminal where your file is present" do you mean open up the terminal within my python editor aka pycharm?

Comment: please remove all the failed attempts in your output to make it more clear what you are asking

Answer (score 17):

You can also use homebrew

```
brew install geckodriver
```

[or npm](https://www.kenst.com/2016/12/installing-marionette-firefoxdriver-on-mac-osx/)

```
npm install geckodriver
```

Answer (score 4):

1. You need to download it first using i.e. [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) command

   ```
   cd /tmp
   wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.25.0/geckodriver-v0.25.0-macos.tar.gz
   ```
2. Then you need to unpack it using [tar](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tar.1.html) command

   ```
   tar xzf geckodriver-v0.25.0-macos.tar.gz
   ```
3. Just in case you can also make it executable using [chmod](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod) command

   ```
   chmod +x geckodriver
   ```
4. Now you can instantiate Firefox browser instance providing path to the Geckodriver using [executable_path parameter](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver) like

   ```
   from selenium import webdriver
   driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/tmp/geckodriver')
   driver.get('http://example.com')
   ```

Check out [Selenium With Python](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Selenium+With+Python) article for more information on properly instantiating Firefox browser using WebDriver Python API.

Comment: Thank you! @Dmitri T This is giving a few errors:                                                               
Brandons-MacBook-Pro-3:tmp Brandon$ tar xzf geckodriver-v0.25.0-macos.tar.gz
Brandons-MacBook-Pro-3:tmp Brandon$ chmod +x geckodriver
Brandons-MacBook-Pro-3:tmp Brandon$ from selenium import webdriver
from: can't read /var/mail/selenium
Brandons-MacBook-Pro-3:tmp Brandon$ driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/tmp/geckodriver')
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
Brandons-MacBook-Pro-3:tmp Brandon$ driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/tmp/geckodriver')